# How to insert structures into a hashing function in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, struct, hashtable

I finished doing my hashing function, and now it seems to be printing the same address rather than all of them. also it just prints the exact same address over and over again I am almost sure that the error is in the "Put" function since it is this one the one that adds to the array of structs. but I leave all the code here just in case the bug is somewhere else. I get the data from a file for testing any file in ASCII can be used. Thanks for the advice in advance!

the structures I made are here:

```
typedef struct HashNode{
char* key;
int data; 
struct HashNode* next;
} HashNode;

typedef struct Hashtable{
int size;   
struct HashNode** hashArray; 
} Hashtable;`
```

there must be something wrong with them because they don't hold what I input in them.

Comment: `hashtable->hashArray = malloc(sizeof(HashNode*)*TABLE_LENGTH);` Or clearer : `hashtable->hashArray = malloc(sizeof(TABLE_LENGTH * sizeof *hashtable->hashArray);`

Comment: in `Put()` node->key = keyWord; refers to the original keyword, supplied by the caller's `word`. You'll need a `strdup()` here.

Comment: please explain further! at the moment with some changes from claptrap's comment it got to print different values for each output however the word printed out seems to be the same all the time. which is the last word on the text file. Thanks

Comment: Plus: in a lot of places (loops) you refer to `TABLE_LENGTH`, you already stored that value in the hashtable struct via : `hashtable->size = TABLE_LENGTH;` , you could refer to `hashtable->size` instead of the constant.

Comment: By the way I am printing from the first function--- last if statement. right now seems like a printing problem I am also looking for things to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `Put` always the same string, `word`, into your hash as key. That string is being overwtitten repeatedly and has the contents of the last key. (What's worse, the has value of the nodes won't match the keys except the last.)

One way to fix this is to make the hash table own the keys: Either copy them (perhaps with `strdup`) or make the key in the structure an array and `strcpy` to that. When you copy them, you must do so only when the key is first inserted into the has table, not when the value with an existing key is overwritten. When you use an array, you can obviouslay only handle strings up to a certain length.

Another way is to make sure that all keys point to different memory addresses. That is the case if you store the whole input in memory and make the keys pointers into that memory, perhaps the results from `strtok`. The input memory must live at least as long as the hash table.

**Edit**: Your code for reading the words limits words to 32 chars (without enforcing that limit!). So a quick fix to your code would be to make the `key` entry in youir node an array of 32 chars:

```
typedef struct HashNode {
    char key[32];
    int data;
    struct HashNode *next;
} HashNode;
```

You must then copy then contents to the key in `Put`. Replace

```
node->key = keyWord;
```

with:

```
strcpy(node->key, keyWord);
```

This will make the counting work, but your code still has several other issues. For example:

- You add the empty string if you have consecutive spaces.
- You also should not allocate memory for the node up front in `Put`, only in the case where a new node is really needed. Otherwise you'll leak memory.
- The hash value should be calculated by `Put`, not by the client code to enforce that the same hash function is used throughout.

Comment: right on! how would I fix the empty string problem??

Comment: You could `Put` words in the table only if `letters > 0`.

Comment: Thank you! I did not do it back then

Answer (score 0):

In your code you write

```
// if the address is populated, but the incoming node has the same key as the
// node in place just update the counter
if(strcmp(hashtable->hashArray[value]->key, node->key)) { 
        hashtable->hashArray[value]->data += node->data;// +1
```

but the comment doesn't seem to match your code, for it to match you should check if strcmp returns 0, i.e. when keys match:

```
if(!strcmp(hashtable->hashArray[value]->key, node->key)) { 
        hashtable->hashArray[value]->data += node->data;// +1
```

Comment: very good observation Mr claptrap let me check if it did the big difference!

Comment: ok we got some progress!! now it is printing different numbers but stilll the same words...                                             Output:                                                                   works , 2911 works , 1 works , 1 works , 2 works , 10 works , 3 works , 1 works , 1 works , 4 works , 2 works